# Avoid grabbing nothing from string stream

Tags: c++, parsing, string, stringstream

I'm working on an assembler for a very basic ISA. Currently I'm implementing parser function and I'm using a string stream to grab words from lines. Here's an example of the assembly code:

```
; This program counts from 10 to 0
        .ORIG x3000
        LEA R0, TEN     ; This instruction will be loaded into memory location x3000
        LDW R1, R0, #0
START   ADD R1, R1, #-1
        BRZ DONE
        BR  START
                        ; blank line
DONE    TRAP    x25     ; The last executable instruction
TEN     .FILL   x000A   ; This is 10 in 2's comp, hexadecimal
        .END
```

Don't worry about the nature of the assembly code, simply look at line 3, the one with the comment to the right. My parser functions aren't complete, but here's what I have:

```
// Define three conditions to code
enum {DONE, OK, EMPTY_LINE};
// Tuple containing a condition and a string vector
typedef tuple<int,vector<string>> Code;

// Passed an alias to a string
// Parses the line passed to it
Code ReadAndParse(string& line)
{

    /***********************************************/
    /****************REMOVE COMMENTS****************/
    /***********************************************/
    // Sentinel to flag down position of first
    // semicolon and the index position itself
    bool found = false;
    size_t semicolonIndex = -1;

    // Convert the line to lowercase
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        line[i] = tolower(line[i]);

        // Find first semicolon
        if(line[i] == ';' && !found)
        {
            semicolonIndex = i;
            // Throw the flag
            found = true;
        }
    }

    // Erase anything to and from semicolon to ignore comments
    if(found != false)
        line.erase(semicolonIndex);


    /***********************************************/
    /*****TEST AND SEE IF THERE'S ANYTHING LEFT*****/
    /***********************************************/

    // To snatch and store words
    Code code;
    string token;
    stringstream ss(line);
    vector<string> words;

    // While the string stream is still of use
    while(ss.good())
    {
        // Send the next string to the token
        ss >> token;
        // Push it onto the words vector
        words.push_back(token);

        // If all we got was nothing, it's an empty line
        if(token == "")
        {
            code = make_tuple(EMPTY_LINE, words);
            return code;
        }
    }

    /***********************************************/
    /***********DETERMINE OUR TYPE OF CODE**********/
    /***********************************************/


    // At this point it should be fine
    code = make_tuple(OK, words);
    return code;
}
```

As you can see, the Code tuple contains a condition represented in the enum decleration and vector containing all words in the line. What I want is to have every word in a line pushed into the vector and then returned.

The issue arises on the third call of the function (the third line of the assembly code). I use the ss.good() function to determine if I have any words in the string stream. For some reason the ss.good() function returns true even though there is no fourth word in the third line and I end up having the words [lea] [r0,] [ten] and [ten] pushed into the vector. ss.good() is true on the fourth call and token receives nothing, thus I have [ten] pushed into the vector twice.

I notice if I remove the spaces between the semicolon and the last word, this error doesn't occur. I want to know how to get the right number of words pushed into the vector.

Please don't recommend Boost library. I love the library, but I want to keep this project simple. This is nothing big, there's only a dozen instructions for this processor. Also, bear in mind that this function is only half-baked, I'm testing and debugging it incrementally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stream's error flags only get set *after* the condition (such as reaching the end of the stream) has occurred.

Try replacing your loop condition with:

```
while(ss >> token)
{
    // Push it onto the words vector
    words.push_back(token);

    // If all we got was nothing, it's an empty line
    if(token == "")
    {
        code = make_tuple(EMPTY_LINE, words);
        return code;
    }
}
```

With this code, I get the following tokens for line 3:

```
"LEA"
"R0,"
"TEN"
";"
"This"
"instruction"
"will"
"be"
"loaded"
"into"
"memory"
"location"
"x3000"
```

I know the language you're trying to parse is a simple one. Nonetheless you would do yourself a favour if you would consider using a specialized tool for the job such as, for example, [`flex`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser).

Comment: +1.  Wow, somehow it didn't show your post until a second before I posted mine.  Weird.  Deleting mine since it is dupe.  I will add, however, see this FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.2